# Круглая граница вокруг иконки

Tags: html, css, border

Как сделать вокруг иконок круглые границы что бы они не превращались в овалы?

***Home.html***

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta oncontextmenu="return false;">
    <title>Photography</title>
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/a076d05399.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Home.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/swiper/swiper-bundle.min.css">
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/swiper/swiper-bundle.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../package/swiper-bundle.min.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <script src="Home.js"></script>

    <header class="background">
      <h1 class="logo">Name</h1>
      <h3 class="sub_logo">Photography</h3>

      <nav>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="Home.html" class="active">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="Gallery.html">Gallery</a></li>
          <li><a href="About.html">About</a></li>
          <li><a href="Contact.html">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </header>

    <section class="header-photo">
      <img src="img/image.png">
      <h1>Name</h1>
    </section>

    
    <section class="social-networks">
      <div class="sn-content">
        <a href="https://www.instagram.com/agurec.ph/" class="instagram"><i class="fab fa-instagram"></i></a>
        <a href="https://www.facebook.com/messages/t/stas.zakharov.35" class="facebook-messenger"><i class="fab fa-facebook-messenger"></i></a>
      </div>
    </section>

    <h1 class="latest">Latest: </h1>

    <div class="swiper-container">
      <div class="swiper-wrapper">
        <img src="img/wheel.jpg" class="swiper-slide" oncontextmenu="return false;">
        <img src="img/car_filtered_wide.jpg" class="swiper-slide">
        <img src="img/car_park_bg.jpg" class="swiper-slide">
        <img src="img/car_build_bg.jpg" class="swiper-slide">
        <img src="img/car_road_bg.jpg" class="swiper-slide">
      </div>

      <div class="swiper-pagination"></div>
      <div class="swiper-button-prev"></div>
      <div class="swiper-button-next"></div>
    </div>

    <h1 class="top">Top:</h1>

    <!-- Site photos -->

    <div class="top-photos-gallery">
      <div class="image-slide">
        <img src="img/wheel.jpg" onclick="openModal();currentSlide(1)" class="hover-shadow">
      </div>
      <div class="image-slide">
        <img src="img/car_filtered_wide.jpg" onclick="openModal();currentSlide(2)" class="hover-shadow">
      </div>
      <div class="image-slide">
        <img src="img/car_park_bg.jpg" onclick="openModal();currentSlide(3)" class="hover-shadow">
      </div>
      <div class="image-slide">
        <img src="img/car_road_bg.jpg" onclick="openModal();currentSlide(4)" class="hover-shadow">
      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Modal -->

    <div id="Modal" class="modal">
      <span class="close cursor" onclick="closeModal()">&times;</span>
      <div class="modal-content">

        <div class="Slides">
          <div class="numbertext">1 / 4</div>
          <img src="img/wheel.jpg">
        </div>

        <div class="Slides">
          <div class="numbertext">2 / 4</div>
          <img src="img/car_filtered_wide.jpg">
        </div>

        <div class="Slides">
          <div class="numbertext">3 / 4</div>
          <img src="img/car_park_bg.jpg">
        </div>

        <div class="Slides">
          <div class="numbertext">4 / 4</div>
          <img src="img/car_road_bg.jpg">
        </div>

        <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1)">&#10094;</a>
        <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1)">&#10095;</a>
      </div>
    </div>

    <script>
      function openModal() {
        document.getElementById("Modal").style.display = "block";
      }
      
      function closeModal() {
        document.getElementById("Modal").style.display = "none";
      }
      
      var slideIndex = 1;
      showSlides(slideIndex);
      
      function plusSlides(n) {
        showSlides(slideIndex += n);
      }
      
      function currentSlide(n) {
        showSlides(slideIndex = n);
      }
      
      function showSlides(n) {
        var i;
        var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("Slides");
        var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("demo");
        var captionText = document.getElementById("caption");
        if (n > slides.length) {slideIndex = 1}
        if (n < 1) {slideIndex = slides.length}
        for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
          slides[i].style.display = "none";
        }
        for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
          dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
        }
        slides[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";
        dots[slideIndex-1].className += " active";
        captionText.innerHTML = dots[slideIndex-1].alt;
      }
    </script>

    <script src="../package/swiper-bundle.min.js"></script>

    <script>
     Swiper.use(myPlugin);

     var swiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container', {
       pagination: {
         el: '.swiper-pagination',
         clickable: true,
       },
       navigation: {
         nextEl: '.swiper-button-next',
         prevEl: '.swiper-button-prev',
       },
       debugger: true,
     });
    </script>

    <footer>
      <div class="text"></div>
        <h4>&copy; Stanislav Zakharov</h4>
        <h5>Made by: <span>Vladislav Zakharov</span></h5>
    </footer>
  </body>
</html>
```

***Home.csss***

```
*{
  font-family: "montserrat", sans-serif;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  margin-top: -10px;
  padding: 0;
}


body {
  background-color: #ececec;
  font-family: "Helvetica Neue", "Helvetica", "Arial", sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #fff;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.background {
  background: #333;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100%;
}

.background h1.logo {
  font-size: 29px;
  margin-left: 30px;
  transform: translateY(80%);
  color: #e3e3e3;
}

.background h3.sub_logo {
  font-size: 19px;
  margin-left: 30px;
  transform: translateY(170%);
  color: #e3e3e3;
}

.background nav {
  height: 120px;
  width: 100%;
}

.background ul {
  float: right;
  margin-right: 30px;
  transform: translateY(135%);
}

.background ul li {
  display: inline-block;
}

.background ul li a,
.background ul li a:after {
  transition: all .3s;
}

.background ul li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 21px;
  padding: 10px 15px;
  position: relative;
}

.background ul li a:after {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: auto;
  width: 0%;
  content: ".";
  color: transparent;
  background: #aaa;
  height: 1px;
}

.background ul li a:hover:after {
  width: 100%;
}

.background ul li a.active {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: yellow;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  font-size: 21px;
  padding: 10px 15px;
  position: relative;
}

.background ul li a.active:after {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: auto;
  width: 0%;
  content: ".";
  color: transparent;
  height: 1px;
}

.background ul li a.active:hover:after {
  width: 100%;
}

.main-part {
  height: auto;
  width: 80%;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
  transform: translateX(13%);
  margin-top: 10px;
  background-color: #fff;
}

.header-photo {
  margin-top: 10px;
  filter: brightness(30%);
}

.header-photo img {
  border-bottom: 2px solid #000;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.header-photo h1 {
  font-size: 70px;
  color: #fff;
  transform: translateY(-430%);
}

h2.latest {
  color: #333;
  letter-spacing: 0.2em;
  text-align: center;
  transform: translateY(500%);
  transition: .5s;
}
.swiper-container {
  width: 70%;
  height: 90%;
  margin-top: 100px;
  border: 2px solid #000;
}

.swiper-wrapper {
  padding-top: 18px;
  padding-bottom: 40px;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.swiper-slide {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 18px;
  background: #fff;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  padding-bottom: 40px;
}

.swiper-pagination {
  height: 10px;
  width: 200px;
  padding-bottom: 25px;
}

.swiper-wrapper img {
  height: 100.38%;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}

.swiper-button-prev {
  margin-left: 20px;
}

.swiper-button-next {
  margin-right: 20px;
}

.latest {
  color: #000;
  text-align: center;
  letter-spacing: 0.1em;
  transform: translateY(60%);
  font-size: 80px;
  font-weight: bold;
}
/*-------------------------------------------*/

/*-------------------------------------------*/

.top {
  font-size: 50px;
  color: #000;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #000;
  border-top: 2px solid #000;
  padding: 15px;
  margin-left: 290px;
  margin-right: 290px;
  text-align: center;
  transform: translateY(170%);
}

.top-photos-gallery {
  transform: translateY(7%);
  border: 2px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9);
  padding: 2px 0 auto;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 15px;
  margin-left: 295px;
  margin-right: 295px;
}

.image-slide {
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;
  align-content: center;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  padding-top: 20px;
}

.image-slide img {
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.top-photos-gallery::after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

.modal {
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 110%;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
}

.modal-content {
  position: relative;
  background: transparent;
  padding: 0;
  transform: translateY(8%);
  margin-left: 300px;
  width: 90%;
  max-width: 1200px;
}

.close {
  color: white;
  position: absolute;
  top: 45px;
  right: 45px;
  font-size: 55px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
  color: #999;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.Slides {
  display: none;
}

.prev,
.next {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  width: auto;
  padding: 16px;
  margin-top: -50px;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 40px;
  transition: 0.6s ease;
  border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
  user-select: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
}

.next {
  transform: translateX(2302%);
  border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
}

.prev:hover,
.next:hover {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
}

.numbertext {
  color: #f2f2f2;
  font-size: 22px;
  padding: 8px 12px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}

.caption-container {
  text-align: center;
  background-color: black;
  padding: 2px 16px;
  color: white;
}

img.demo {
  opacity: 0.6;
}

.active,
.demo:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}

img.hover-shadow {
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.hover-shadow:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
}

/*-----------------------------------------*/

.social-networks {
  background-color: transparent;
  height: 150px;
  width: 30%;
  text-align: center;
  transform: translateY(-270%);
}

.sn-content {
  transform: translateY(30%);
}

.sn-content a {
  border: solid 1px #000;
  border-radius: 50%;
  font-size: 80px;
  padding: 20px;
}

/*-----------------------------------------*/
footer {
  border-top: 3px solid #333;
  border-radius: 3px;
  padding: 20px;
  transform: translateY(900%);
  color: #000;
  text-align: center;
}

footer h4 {
  font-size: 20px;
}

footer h5 {
  transform: translateY(60%);
}
```

Comment: Чтобы из border-radius: 50% вышел круг, нужно или изначально иметь квадрат, или строго указать квадратные размеры width / height. P.s. а точно необходимо было копировать сюда весь сайт, а не один овальный блок?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Border-radius: 9999px;
```

Поставит круглые одинаковые углы, для полного круга, у блока высота должна быть равна ширине
Для этого нужно либо вручную приравнивать одно к другому с помощью джс, либо использовать относительные единицы измерения, типа: vh, vw, vmin, vmax
Так же можно вручную задать в пикселях размеры